# How to assign text to textbox field in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-bootstrap

component:

BaseForm:

```
        );
    }
```

I could able to get the student data from database. this.props.firstname prints the exact value to the page. But I need to render the same value to textbox React Feild. I tried to create value property in Field and assign the value to it () , which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on Field control that you use, though if it passes all its props to subcomponent you can pass via the *value* property in the following way:

```
<Field name="firstName" component={this.renderTextField}
       value={this.props.firstName} className="form-control"
       label="Enter your first name" />
```

Few comments on your code:

1. React guidelines suggest that you name components starting with capital letter, .e.g `BaseForm.RenderTextField`
2. on extending BaseForm - React team suggests to build components composition instead of extending/subclassing, that will make code cleaner. Especially considering your BaseForm.renderTextField does not refer to this E.g.

   ```
   export default class StudentForm extends React.Component {
   ...
       <Field name="firstName" component={BaseForm.RenderTextField} 
          className="form-control" label="Enter your first name"
          value={this.props.firstName} />
   ```